# extract string from txt file

Tags: excel, vba

*background*

I have to create a code in Excel VBA which opens a text file and writes a specific part of some of its strings beginning with ":60F" into a specific cell of the Excel sheet.

This part of the code already works.

*issue*

However, I´m struggling with the second part of the task. I have to write into another cell of the Excel document a part of a specific string beginning with ":61:".

The problem is, that there are many strings in the text file beginning with "61:", but I need the one which occurs right after the string beginning with "60F:".

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me with this. Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards

Here is the code I wrote so far:

*code*

```
Function extract_opening_balance(ByVal filename As String, subfield_61 As String) As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim pos1 As Integer

strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Data of Reporting Month\"
filename = strPath & "MT940_T2_" & main_menu.cbo_Year & Left(main_menu.cbo_Month, 2) & Format(day(CDate(Right(main_menu.lst_Date.List(i), 10))), "00") & ".txt"

Open filename For Input As #1
    For i = 3 To 13
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline

                        If InStr(textline, ":60F:") > 0 Then


                    If InStr(textline, "EUR") = 13 And InStr(textline, 0) <> 16 Then
                        'For j = 1 To String(":60F:").Count

                            pos1 = InStr(subfield_61, "//") + 30

                            'time_str = Mid(subfield_61, pos1, 6)
                            'time_str = Mid(time_str, 1, 2) & ":" & Mid(time_str, 3, 2) & ":" & Mid(time_str, 5, 2)

                            Sheets("op_balance").Range("B" & i).Value = Mid(textline, 6, 1)
                            Sheets("op_balance").Range("C" & i).Value = Mid(textline, 16, 20)
                            Sheets("op_balance").Range("D" & i).Value = subfield_61
                            Sheets("op_balance").Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-3]=""D"",(-1)*RC[-2],RC[-2])"


                       'Next j
                    End If
            End If
        Loop
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: How big is the text file? Can you provide a short sample of what would be in it?

Comment: [Seek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7af2feyt(v=vs.90).aspx) and ye shall [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Comment: The [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx)  allows for a place to start your search. Record the position of `:60F` (into a long perhaps) and use it as the point to start looking for `:61:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Regexp` option:

> random stuff
>   random guy
>   Stuff :60F:stuff
>   other stuff 61:getme
>   60F more

returns alphanumerics after *61:* (preceded by *:60F:*), ie *getme* in this example

```
Sub GetMe()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FH As Object
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Dim strIn As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FH = FSO.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\test.txt")
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strIn = FH.readall
strIn = Replace(strIn, vbNewLine, Chr(32))

With objRegex
    .Pattern = ":60F.*61:(\w+)"
    If .Test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegexMC = .Execute(strIn)
        MsgBox objRegexMC(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        MsgBox "text not found"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, brettdj! You really helped me a lot.